# where is url specified when connecting to Oracle in C code

Tags: c, linux, oracle, url

I searched around and get something like this:
(1)EXEC SQL CONNECT :username IDENTIFIED BY :password;
(2)con.Connect("test", "tester", "tester", SA_Oracle_Client);

But could not find the missing step of connection to URL where Oracle locates. It is standard to have a URL in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that makefile uses TNS related info for Oracle connection.